# How to make NSOperation con-current with out adding to NSOperationQueue in iPhone

Tags: iphone, concurrency, nsoperation

I am trying to create an NSOperation by subclassing from NSOperation.I want my operation to be executed on a separate thread as well as it should support canceling option i.e i should be able to stop the thread(or the operation) at any point of time.I tried adding my operation instance to NSOperationQueue,everything is working fine but "the operation" is being executed after some time which makes my application slow.So i tried running my operation alone by calling `[theOperation start];` its pretty fast but executing on the main thread.How to make the NSOperation run on separate thread with canceling option please help.

Comment: Which operation queue did you use: `mainQueue` or your own created instance?

Comment: i used NSOperationQueue's instance by allocing NSOperationQueue class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either:

1) do not make it an NSOperation and explicitly create a thread.

2) use a second operation queue and/or increase the priority.

3) use a container type for the result. when you need it immediately, cancel the background load operation and load manually.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to implement `- (BOOL)isConcurrent`:

```
- (BOOL)isConcurrent
{
    return YES;
}
```

But there are implications. Read the [Apple reference docs on NSOperation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html), particularly the section *Subclassing Notes*. Also note that if you want the operation to be cancellable, you need to implement the cancelling behaviour yourself: eg, in your `main` selector you need to check if the operation has been cancelled, and immediately return if it has.

Comment: i am returning 'YES' from 'isConcurrent' method but its not being run on separate thread its blocking my main thread.

Comment: In your `start` method are you launching your task concurrently, ie, calling `performSelectorInBackground:` or similar? The docs say you need to override `start`, `isExecuting` and `isFinished` as well as `isConcurrent`.

Comment: i tried calling start method's code in backGround but in that case i could not be able to achieve the canceling functionality.

Comment: Yes you would. Add a BOOL property to your class (like `BOOL wasCancelled`); override `- (void)cancel` to set `wasCancelled = YES`; then in your `main` (which you call from `start` in the background), check `wasCancelled` while you're processing your task, and if it becomes YES at any stage then abort the processing and clean up.